# "Table doesn't exist" Issue

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to install a PHP Script for my website, set everything up, imported the SQL file through phpMyAdmin that came with the script, but I am facing a blank white page with an error shown below:

> File   /home/user/public_html/user/include/functions_common.php
>
> Line   511
>
> Sql    select a.* ,a.ratingm as votes , format(ifnull(((a.ratingp*100)/ ( a.ratingm*5))/10,0),1) as rating ,format(ifnull(((a.ratingp*100)/ ( ratingm*5))/20,0),1) as ratings from movies a where featured=1 order by id desc limit 9
>
> Error  Table 'user.movies' doesn't exist

It is strange the script did not come with this table in the SQL imported file, but is there a way to fix this? Is there a way to somehow create the table to make it work right? I am stuck. Thanks.

Comment: The table doesn't exist, so you have to go create it. Look up SQL CREATE

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy table using,

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIES
(`ID` int, `RATINGM` int, `RATINGP` int, `FEATURED` int, `VIEWS` int);
```

Comment: Error

SQL query:

CREATE TABLE MOVIES(
ID NUMBER;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER' at line 3

Comment: @user2056144 Updated to `mysql` syntax. Check now.

Comment: Okay, now after adding that, a new error replaced it, same line and all.                                                                                                                                  File /home/user/public_html/user/include/functions_common.php
Line 511
Sql select a.* ,a.ratingm as votes , format(ifnull(((a.ratingp*100)/ ( a.ratingm*5))/10,0),1) as rating ,format(ifnull(((a.ratingp*100)/ ( ratingm*5))/20,0),1) as ratings from movies a order by views desc limit 9
Error Unknown column 'views' in 'order clause'

Comment: @user2056144 In the question, there was a `order by ID`. Now there is an `order by views`. Are you sure you are running the same thing? Anyways, have added a `VIEWS` column. Check now. Any other error comes, add that in the table creation list and create the table with that column.

Comment: Seems like that problem is fixed, but a new one appeared on a new line, this is what it says:                                                                                                                                    File /home/user/public_html/user/include/functions_common.php
Line 612
Sql select a.*,b.user_name,c.name,c.slug,c.startwith from comments a inner join users b on a.uid=b.id inner join movies c on c.id=a.mid where a.status=1 order by a.id desc limit 10
Error Unknown column 'c.name' in 'field list'